# Any Case Adobe Embed - API Key (Client ID) Will Be Expired?

Tags: angular, adobe, pdf-viewer, adobe-embed-api, adobe-pdfservices

I am new to Adobe PDF Embed API.In any case, newly created API Key (Client ID) will be expired or Usage will be stopped ?

Answer (score 0):

We do not expire API keys for Embed.

Comment: The Adobe PDF Embed API shows that it was free on this website - https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/pricing/main/. Can we use this as a standalone product without purchasing any other services and will it have a cost in future?

Comment: I can not speak for what Adobe will do in the future. It is free now.